# How can I create a Task Scheduler task or otherwise run an SSMS query to save to a file location?

Tags: excel, vba, scheduled-tasks, ssms

I have around 20 SQL queries that we run in SSMS every day, copy the grid results, then paste the results in an excel file.

Is there a way (using task scheduler, or excel, or SSMS, or VBA) that I can have those same queries run on their own at 8am, and save to excel or CSV file ? 
(I prefer not to have to use Excel's ODBC connection since it will have to run on other desktops possibly.)

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use SQL Server Agent, or are you using Express? What have you tried, as there are *plenty* of examples on how to use Task Scheduler as a pseudo SQL Server Agent, and there's a lot of documentation on SQL Server Agent itself if you do have it.

Comment: @Larnu - I guess what you are saying is that there is a lot of info on how to launch a  SSMS query using Task Scheduler?  I can look for that.  A preliminary search didn't turn up anything.  Also can't seem to see how to get SSMS to automatically save query results.  And we don't have SQL server agent nor can we get it.

Comment: You wouldn't launch SSMS, no, you'd likely use `sqlcmd`. In regards to *" And we don't have SQL server agent"* So you *are* using Express?

Comment: @Lamu - we are using SQL Server Management Studio 2016

Comment: @Lamu - I'm checking with HD to see if we can get Sql Server Agent added

Comment: *"we are using SQL Server Management Studio 2016"* that's an IDE; I asked about what edition of SQL Server you're using, I.e. Express, Standard, Web, Enterprise. What does `PRINT @@VERSION;` return?

Comment: @lamu 
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP3) (KB4022619) - 12.0.6024.0 (X64) 
 Sep  7 2018 01:37:51 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: )

Comment: You have enterprise (a very expensive version of SQL Server) this is definitely a task to put into Agent. You'll have some very qualified DBAs and SQL Developers who can do this for you.

Comment: @Lamu - thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not a 100% exact solution, BUT, there is an add-in [SSMSBoost](https://www.ssmsboost.com) that I develop, it has "Results grid scripting" feature, which exports all grids to excel-compatible "open document spreadsheet" (XML format).
Literally, you run all your 20 queries in 1 batch, get 20 results grids and click 1 button: "Start Scripting" (after pre-configuring the scripter to save every grid to separate file (or it can export each grid to own spreadsheet within 1 file).
Does it help? Yes, you still will have to "run" manually, but SSMSBoost will take care about exporting everything with 1 click.

The feature is described here: https://www.ssmsboost.com/Features/ssms-add-in-results-grid-script-results
There is also a short video about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=waDCukeXeLU